# Rails: updating partial dosen't execute inline javascript from the partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, load

I am updating  DIV element on Onchange event of dropdown. And I am using partial to replace the content in the DIV. Here is my ajax call:

```
  var cach_this = this;
        $j.ajax({
            url: url,
            context: document.body,
            complete: function(text,status){
                cach_this.runtime_container[0].innerHTML = text.responseText;
            }
        });
```

url: is call to controllers method

And from controller it will render like this:

```
render :partial => "choose_by_all", :locals => {:uniq_id => params[:uniq_id]}, :layout => false
```

The partial content gets loaded perfectly, But inline javascript in partial dosen't execute.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with the same problem in one of my Rails 2 app, after days of Googling, reading docs etc it turned out that Javascript is executed on page load. Loading a partial with some Javascript function in it will not fire unless to explicitly call the function.